# How to not-inherit a style from parent element

Tags: css, opacity

I have a CSS-element with opacity above a picture in the background.
Inside that element there is an image, that inherits the opacity, so the image is somewhat darker than it would be normal:

```
<body>
 <div class="trans">
  <img class="not_trans" src="test.png">
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
 background:url(stars.gif);
 background-color:black;
}
.trans{
 opacity:0.4;
}
img.not_trans{
 opacity:1.0;
}
```

But the image is still half transparent.

How can I achieve a normal non-transparent image without moving the `img` out of the `div`?

If there are a lot of elements cascaded with different background-colors, using
`background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` instead of `opacity` is not an easy option

I only want one `img` element not to inherit the transparency of the surrounding elements

At least there would be a solution with javascript:

1. move the img tag in the DOM out of the div
2. set a spacer there instead
3. position the `img` where it was with `position:absolute`

But is there a solution with CSS?

Comment: Can you update your code to show your multiple-image situation, because I don't fully understand what you are after. A jsFiddle would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Use rgba on your `.trans` instead of opacity! Like rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); or whatever color you have.

Comment: that solves the first example, but not my problem, cause I have a lot of more elements-cascaded and I only want one element not to inherit the transparency. I will clarify the question...